# Meteor + Polymer + Vulcanize + Android = Clunky UI

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, polymer

We have a very simple mobile application written using Polymer over Meteor. There are only a handful of pages and each contains very few elements. No fancy animations (beyond Polymer built in animations) or large data sets.
When running on a web browser, the site runs smoothly. When running on a mobile device, the ui feels slow and Polymers animations look sluggish and less responsive.
How do we even start profiling the problem? Is that expected from running on a mobile device? 
Any leads will help... Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's caused by Meteor + Polymer, you may try to use Polymer only .... as it has been tested on mobile device with no issues...

Comment: https://github.com/HedCET/TorrentAlert